# PHP fake average rating generator

Tags: php, random, rating, faker

Let's imagine that the material has a rating of 2.7 with 7 votes.
I want to create a script that would generate my desired rating that would look real and not fake.

For example, I want the rating to change from 2.7 to 4.6, but the number of votes should also change proportionally.
I can't figure out how to implement it correctly.
My script will make the rating 6.0 as I want, but as a result the number of votes will be as high as 500+. I want to refine the script so that it is more realistic and changes the rating with minimal votes
My code:

My script will make the rating 6.0 as I want for example, but the number of votes will be as high as 500+. I want to generate the average values of the rating based on the previous values, while the deviation in the votes should not look fake.

```
<?php

class RatingFaker
{
    private $totalRating = 10; // Maximum rating threshold (5 or 10)
    private $maxRatingGenerate = 10; // We generate maximum rating values during the passage
    private $minRatingGenerarate = 5; // Minimally generates a rating value during a pass
    private $minRatingCheck = 3.5; // The minimum acceptable threshold from which we start to act
    
    public function __construct($minRatingCheck)
    {
        $this->minRatingCheck = $minRatingCheck;
    }
    
    private function calcAverageRating($ratings = []) 
    {
        $totalWeight = 0;
        $totalReviews = 0;
    
        foreach ($ratings as $weight => $numberofReviews) {
            $WeightMultipliedByNumber = $weight * $numberofReviews;
            $totalWeight += $WeightMultipliedByNumber;
            $totalReviews += $numberofReviews;
            }
    
        //divide the total weight by total number of reviews
        $averageRating = $totalWeight / $totalReviews;
    
        return [
            'rating' => $averageRating,
            'vote_num' => $totalReviews
        ];
    }
    
    private function getRandVoters()
    {
        $randRating = rand($this->minRatingGenerarate, $this->maxRatingGenerate);
        $randVoters = rand(1, 99);
        
        return [
            $randRating => $randVoters
        ];
    }
    
    private function ratingLoop($valueList)
    {
        $valueList = array_merge($valueList, $this->getRandVoters());
        
        $newRating = $this->calcAverageRating($valueList);
        
        if($newRating['rating'] < $this->minRatingCheck) {
            $valueList = array_merge($valueList, $this->getRandVoters());
            
            return $this->ratingLoop($valueList);
        }
        
        if($newRating['rating'] > 10) {
            $newRating['rating'] = 10;
        }
        
        return [
            'rating' => round($newRating['rating'], 1),
            'sum' => round($newRating['vote_num'] * round($newRating['rating'], 1)),
            'voters' => $newRating['vote_num']
        ];
    }
    
    public function check($currentRate, $currentVoteNum)
    {
        if($currentRate < $this->minRatingCheck) {
            $rating = $this->ratingLoop([
                $currentRate => $currentVoteNum,
            ]);
        }
        
        return $rating ?? [];
    }
}

$currentRate = 2.4;
$voteNum = 88;
$oldRating = [
    'rating' => $currentRate,
    'sum' => round($voteNum * $currentRate),
    'voters' => $voteNum
];
$rating = [];

$ratingFaker = new RatingFaker(6.0);
$rating = $ratingFaker->check($currentRate, $voteNum);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Was:';
print_r($oldRating);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo 'Now:';
print_r($rating);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: "**My example seems to work,**", so what is the problem?  "**but it is very incorrect and implausible.**"  What parts are incorrect/implausible, if it works ?

Comment: As I indicated, it is generated implausibly.
For example, now the rating is 2.5 based on 9 votes.
My script will make the rating 6.0 as I want, but as a result the number of votes will be as high as 500+.
I want to refine the script so that it is more realistic and changes the rating with minimal votes

Comment: You're being very unclear about what it actually is you want to do. The fact that you cannot properly put into words what the code should do is probably the reason you cannot code it correctly. We cannot guess what it really is you want your code to do.

Comment: I clearly indicated that I want to generate the average values of the rating based on the previous values, while the deviation in the votes should not look fake.

Comment: "now the rating is 2.5 based on 9 votes. My script will make the rating 6.0"  You should guess 37.5 as next vote (see: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/%5Cleft(%5Cleft(2.5%5Ccdot9%5Cright)%2Bx%5Cright)%2F10%20%3D%206?or=input )

Comment: This is exactly what is needed, thank you! All my code above just goes to the trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the current rating is 2.5 based on 9 votes, and you want to get a rating of 6.0 with a minimal number of votes, you need to make sure the total value of 10 votes is 60 ( 60/10 = 6.0 ).

The current rating is : `( 2.5*9 / 9 ) = 2.5`

With you extra vote it is: `( (2.5*9+x) / 10 ) = 6.0`

Now you only have to find the correct value for x, which is [37.5](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/%5Cleft(%5Cleft(2.5%5Ccdot9%5Cright)%2Bx%5Cright)%2F10%20%3D%206?or=input)